# Find common attributes among given products in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to find all attributes that are common to a given set of products (Stock_ID numbers). I have a table called Stock_Attributes that contains product info. It looks something like this:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+
| Stock_ID | Attribute_ID | Value      |
+----------+--------------+------------+
|     1001 |            2 | Farmhouse  |
|     1001 |            8 | Blue       |
|     1001 |            9 | Bronze     |
|     1001 |           10 | Metal      |
|     1001 |           10 | Wood       |
|     1002 |            2 | Industrial |
|     1002 |            9 | Chrome     |
|     1002 |           10 | Metal      |
|     1003 |            2 | Industrial |
|     1003 |            8 | Red        |
|     1003 |           10 | Glass      |
|     1003 |           10 | Metal      |
+----------+--------------+------------+
```

Stock_ID and Attribute_ID are both have INT as the data type. Value is a sql_variant since some attributes are Dates or Bits. As you can see, any product can have any combination of attributes and more than one attribute of the same type. The desired result for the above sample set would be one just one row, since these products only have one attribute in common (typically there will be several in common):

```
+--------------+------------+
| Attribute_ID | Value      |
+--------------+------------+
|           10 | Metal      |
+--------------+------------+
```

I do not need to return the Stock_ID numbers in this query since we are starting with that information in a temporary table called #TempItemNumbers. I simply need to return a set of Attribute_IDs and Values that are common to all Stock_ID numbers listed in #TempItemNumbers, which is generated via user input.
I do not typically use cursors or dynamic SQL so I am not very familiar with these methods, but I'm thinking this problem will require one or both.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to tag each attribute per value then select only those that were tagged for all stock_id

```
SELECT attribute_id,
       "value"
  FROM (SELECT *, 
               (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT stock_id) 
                  FROM stock_attributes) cnt,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "value", 
                                               attribute_id 
                                      ORDER BY stock_id) rnum
          FROM stock_attributes
       ) a
 WHERE cnt = rnum
```

Result

```
attribute_id    value
10              Metal
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `Top` with `count()` to achieve it. Try this

```
SELECT TOP 1 attribute_id, [value] 
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY attribute_id,[value]  
ORDER  BY Count(*) DESC
```

Comment: I don't want to limit the result set to just one row. I believe this would return whatever attribute is most in common, but not necessarily common to all of the given products.